# SPARQL query with jena java for extracting all classes and subclasses

Tags: sparql, jena, owl

I'm looking for a query that allows me to extract all classes and subclasses in my ontology with OWL format using SPARQL and Jena.

I tried this code but it doesn't work!

```java
String fileName = "C:\\myOnto.owl";
OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_DL_MEM);
try {
File file = new File(fileName);
FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
model.read(reader,null);
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();


Iterator classIter = model.listClasses();
while (classIter.hasNext()) {
OntClass ontClass = (OntClass) classIter.next();
String uri = ontClass.getLocalName();
if(uri != null)
System.out.println(uri);
}
```

Comment: What does that code do instead if it is not working?

Comment: I don't know why you delete your old question...and therefore ignored my comment/questions...which SPARQL query have you tried? Any SPARQL tutorial read so far? It's useless to provide you this basic query when you don't have any SPARQL experience.

Comment: i deleted it to better organise my question using code format, furthermore it's my first time using stackoverflow so sorry if it seems i am ignoring you.I'll answer you i tried more than 10 SPARQL query for exemple SELECT DISTINCT ?c1 ?c2 { ?c1 a owl:Class . OPTIONAL { ?c1 rdfs:subClassOf ?c2 } } and the outputs are my classes and subclasses and my datatype e.g. short, int, byte.. and it's my first experience using sparql i'm trying to learn and i wish i succeed very soon cause i have a deadline for my project. This is the tutorial i'm following https://fr.slideshare.net/rajighawi/java-and-owl

Comment: Ok, next time "edit" your question. Anyways, what's wrong with the SPARQL query in your comment? What doesn't work as you'd expect?

Comment: For exemple my ontology contains thoses classes: actor, adaptativeCapacity, assets and my subclasses are:humain, contexte, risk i'd like as an output to extract them all that's the aim.

Comment: I understand what you want but I don't understand what does **not** work as expected with your query in the comment. What is returned and what is **not** returned but you'd expect to be returned.

Comment: I also don't understand what you mean by your code doesn't work? Do you get an exception? Please clarify "it doesn't work"